# send/update integer to flask with Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I created a website using flask with a running sqlite-db (SQLAlchemy). I want to send an integer with javascript to flask and back. I know AJAX can be used to accomplish that, but I don't know how to send the integer whenever my if/else-statement within my javascript game is met.

**`games.html`**

```
if (loc == unicornloc) {
    money = 5000;
    alert("\n\nBRAVO! You found the Unicorn! :)");
    }else {
        money = -250;
        alert("The unicorn isn't here :(")
    }

<FORM method="POST" name="searchb">
<input type=checkbox onClick="javascript:search('x1y1');">
<input type=checkbox onClick="javascript:search('x1y2');">
<input type=checkbox onClick="javascript:search('x1y3');">
```

**`games.py`**

```
@app.route('/games/<money>',methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def games(money):
    print(request.args.get('money', type=int))
    return render_template('games.html',money)
```

I want to get the money-value to `flask`, calculate a new value, pass it to my `db` and show the updated value on my website without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

first set up jquery in your html.
make sure that the jquery is included in your head section of the html page:
You won't need to submit a form to update the server it is enough if you put a listener on one of your buttons that sends an ajax request every time it is clicked:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

var sendServerNotification = function(status){

        var urlToCall = '/games/' + status;
         $.ajax({
            url : urlToCall, // the endpoint
            type : "GET", // http method

    // handle a successful response
    success : function(parentDescriptions) {
        console.log('success'); // log the returned json to the console
        // update the page with jquery

    },

    // handle a non-successful response
    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
    }
});

}

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#obsevervedbutton').click(function{
         //we read the value that the user wants to submit: 
         var valueToSubmit = $('#valueToSubmit').val()
         // here you can check if you want to submit the value 
         // or not
         if(true){
            sendServerNotification(valueToSubmit);

         }

         });
    });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
 <button id="obsevervedbutton">notify server</button>
 <input id="valueToSubmit"></input>
</body>
```

and on your server side it is important to return a json response instaed of a normal http response to finish the ajax request and invoke either the success or error url:

```
def games(money):
    print(request.args.get('money', type=int))
    # update the database here
    return json.dumps({"result":"operation successfull!"})
```

I hope this will get you going.

Comment: Is the server notification needed to get the money value get send every time it's changed or .. ? I am kind of confused this looks more complicated than expected just to get an int  ^_^